# Uniformly continuous $f$ in $L^p([0,\infty))$

Tags: measure-theory, problem-solving

Assume that $1\leq p < \infty $,  $f \in L^p([0,\infty))$, and $f$ is uniformly continuous. Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ .

Comment: Here's a sketch: suppose there was $\epsilon>0$ and arbitrarily large $x_1, x_2, \dots \to \infty$ such that $f(x) > \epsilon$. Then uniform continuity shows that $f(x) > \epsilon$ in small  (but bounded-below) neighborhoods of each, so...

Comment: Yeonjoo Yoo: Would you please elaborate on where you got stuck, or perhaps let us know if you work out the details from Akhil's sketch? (Incidentally, there is a minor typo in the first sentence of Akhil's comment where it should say $f(x_k)>\epsilon$ for all $k$. More importantly in the second sentence you'll have better luck showing $f(x)>\epsilon/2$ in small (but with length bounded below) intervals at each $x_k$.  More room is helpful because no lower bound was assumed on $f(x_k)-\epsilon$.)

Comment: (Another minor typo: Akhil and I meant $|f(x)|$ where we wrote $f(x)$.)

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/f-uniformly-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-converges-imply-lim-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Suppose for a contradiction that $f(x) \not \to 0$. Together with the definition of uniform continuity, conclude that there exist constants $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta = \delta(\varepsilon) > 0$ such that for any $M > 0$ there exists $x > M$ for which it holds
$$
\int_{(x,x + \delta )} {|f(y)|^p \,dy}  \ge \bigg(\frac{\varepsilon }{2}\bigg)^p \delta .
$$
However, this would imply $\int_{[0,\infty )} {|f(x)|^p \,dx}  = \infty$, a contradiction.