# Limit at infinity of a uniformly continuous integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$f$ uniformly continuous and $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges imply $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/f-uniformly-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-converges-imply-lim-x)

This is an exercise from Berkeley preliminary exams, Fall 1983

Let $ f : [0, \infty ) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ $ be a uniformly continuous function with
the property that

$ \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_{0}^{b} f(x)dx \ $

exists (as a finite limit). Show that

$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0 $

Obviously if the limit exists, it must be $0 \ $; so the problem is to prove that the limit exists. Any hint ?

Comment: Are you sure that the last limit is for $x \to 0$? I guess it should be $x \to +\infty$.

Comment: This is Barbalat's Lemma. A solution can be found here: http://mathproblems123.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/barbalats-lemma/ And the last limit should be with $x \to \infty$, because changing the function near $0$ such that it still remains uniformly continuous does not affect the converge of the integral limit.

Comment: @BeniBogosel: You required $f$ to be positive ($f \colon [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$) but this hypothesis is absent here. While your argument pushes through if $f \in L^1([0, \infty))$, I'm afraid it doesn't work if $f$ is allowed to change sign and $\int \lvert f(x)\rvert\, dx=+\infty$.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro: I have edited

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I know that the hypothesis is $f$ positive in my proof, but the proof does not make use of that hypothesis anywhere but in the place I say that $f(x_n) \to \ell > 0$, which can be assumed WLOG here (the idea is that we assume that there exists a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ such that $f(x_n)$ does not converge to zero). The proof works just fine if you assume that $f(x_n) \to \ell<0$.

Comment: @BeniBogosel: Yes I got it, see comments in martini's answer. Thank you for this comment too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ doesn't exist. Then there is an $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ such that $|f(x_n)| > \epsilon$ for all $n$ (because the limit, if existing, has to be 0). By uniform continuity there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}2$ if $|x-y| < \delta$. It follows that $|f(x)| > \frac{\epsilon}2$ if $|x-x_n| < \delta$ for some $n$. But now $|\int_{x_n-\delta}^{x_n+\delta} f(x)\, dx| > \epsilon\delta$ for all $n$ contradicting $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \to 0$ for $a,b \to \infty$.

Comment: I have the same objection I had in comments to the main post: this argument certainly works if $f$ is non-negative, or if it is $L^1$, but I'm afraid it doesn't if $f$ is allowed to change sign and $\int \lvert f \rvert\, dx=+\infty$. Do you agree?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Why? If $\int_0^\infty f(x) \,dx$ exists as in inproper integral, we need to have $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \to 0$ for $a, b\to \infty$, which yields that there is an $M$ such that $|\int_a^b f(x)\, dx| < \epsilon\delta$ for all $a,b \ge M$. But now I can choose $x_n$ with $x_n - \delta > M$. I don't see where I could have used $f \in L^1$.

Comment: Oh yes, yes, you're right. The fact that $\int_a^bf(x)\, dx \to 0$ is certainly true and you argument contradicts it. I had mistakenly seen a contradiction with $\int\lvert f(x)\rvert \, dx <+\infty$. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @martini Did you mean "Suppose that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) \neq 0$$" in your first sentence?

Comment: @MattN. As I wrote in the paratheses: If the limit exists, it has to be 0, for if it is $c > 0$ (wlog) say, then we would have $f(x) > \frac c2$ for $x \ge N$ ($N$ choosen properly) and $\int_0^\infty f(x)\, dx$ would diverge.

Comment: @martini Oh, I see! Thanks, I missed the point of the question. Sorry for that. : (

Comment: @martini Could it be that in the last line you meant $|\int_{x_n-\delta}^{x_n+\delta} f(x)\, dx| > \frac{\epsilon}{2}\delta$? : ) plus 1 btw

Comment: @MattN. No I mean $\frac{\epsilon}2 \cdot 2\delta = \epsilon\delta$ as the length of $[x_n-\delta, x_n+\delta]$ is $2\delta$ :) ... thx btw

Comment: @martini Oh my, of course! No further questions : )