# Is the limit equal to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I know the statement " If $f\in$$L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is uniformly continuous, then $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}|f(x)|=0$ " is true. How about $f\in$$L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is continuous but not uniformly continuous ? Is true or false ?

Comment: False.  Let the graph of $f$ consist of spikes of height $1$ centered at the integers whose widths tend to zero sufficiently fast. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370317/does-an-absolutely-integrable-function-tend-to-0-as-its-argument-tends-to-infi) contains a bit more detail.

Comment: Try to construct a counterexample. Hint: Try making a function which oscillates more rapidly as $x$ becomes large. Arrange for the integral to still remain bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function
$$f=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi_{[n,n+\frac{1}{n^2}]}$$
whose integral is
$$\int|f|\,d\mu=\int f\,d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int\chi_{[n,n+\frac{1}{n^2}]}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu([n,n+\tfrac{1}{n^2}])=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
so that $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, but $f(n)=1$ for all integers $n\geq 1$, so that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ isn't $0$ (in fact, it doesn't exist).

Now just make a continuous version of $f$ (with trapezoids, or bump functions, etc.)