# In Fourier transform why does the quantity $[fe^{-ikx}]^{\infty}_{-\infty}=0$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let us say we know that the Fourier transform of the function $f(x)$ exists, which means that: 
$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}|f(x)|dx<\infty$$
However, this does not mean that $f(x)\rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \pm\infty$ (according to this question anyway [Does an absolutely integrable function tend to $0$ as its argument tends to infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370317/does-an-absolutely-integrable-function-tend-to-0-as-its-argument-tends-to-infi)). So I cannot see why the value of 
$$[fe^{-ikx}]^{\infty}_{-\infty}=0$$
Please can someone explain?

Comment: Where are you getting $\left.f(x)e^{ikx}\right|_{-∞}^∞ =0$? is this supposed to be Riemann-Lebesgue?

Comment: @CalvinKhor It could be if we can guarantee the inverse Fourier transform exists.

Comment: Thats not in your assumptions. I am asking for context, because I don't know where you would get this expression from, much less ask it to be 0.

Comment: @CalvinKhor it comes from when deriving the Fourier Transform for $f'(x)$ and the relationship that this is given by $ikF(k)$ where $F(k)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$.

Comment: Integration by parts? This only holds for nice enough functions, or if you switch to a distribution.

Comment: By the way it is easy to see that an absolutely integrable function need not converge to 0; take $f = ∑_0^∞ \Bbb 1_{\left(n,n+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks. By 'nice enough functions' do you basically mean a function that tends to 0 as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$ or is there more to it then that?

Comment: Yeah, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

To justify the partial integration, it suffices to have sequences $(x_n)_n, (y_n)_n $ with $x_n\to\infty  $ and $y_n \to -\infty $ with $f\cdot e^{ikx}\bigg |_{y_n}^{x_n} \to 0$ (why?).

Existence of such sequences can be shown as follows: We have
$$
\infty > \int |f (x)|\,dx = \sum_{n \in \Bbb {Z} } \int_{(n,n+1)} |f(x)|\,dx =\sum_n \int_0^1 |f (x+n)|\,dx =\int_0^1 \sum_n |f (x+n)|\,dx.
$$
The steps above can be justified using monotone convergence.

Now, a function with finite  integral is finite almost everywhere, so that we get
$$
\sum_{n \in\Bbb {Z}} |f (x+n)|<\infty 
$$
for almost all $x \in (0,1) $. Since the terms of a convergent series are a null sequence, this easily implies existence of the desired sequences.