# Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}), F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(y) \text{d}y, F \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ then $F$ vanishes at infinity

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Good day,

Currently I am working with the book "Introduction to Fourier Series" by R. Lasser. There we have the following theorem (on page 227):

---

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Set $$F(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y) \chi_{]-\infty,x]} dy$$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $F \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then $$\hat{F}(a)=\frac{1}{ia} \hat f (a)$$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$.

Proof: We know that $F'(x)=f(x)$ holds for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Integration by parts yields
$$\hat F (a) = \lim_{A \to \infty} F(x) \frac{1}{-ia} e^{-iax} \bigg|_{-A}^A+\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \frac{1}{ia} e^{-iax} dx$$
where we have also used Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. Because of its integrability $F$ vanishes in infinity, that is $$\lim_{|A|\rightarrow \infty} F(A)=0.$$

---

I don't get why $F$ vanishes at infinity. It is stated because of its integrability. But I have found an example of an integrable function that doesn't vanish at infinity, see: [Does an absolutely integrable function tend to $0$ as its argument tends to infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370317/does-an-absolutely-integrable-function-tend-to-0-as-its-argument-tends-to-infi)

It might be because of the integral representation of $F$.

Does someone have an idea? I would really appreciate a proof of this statement.

Thanks a lot,
Marvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, it follows that $F(x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{x}{f(y)\text{ d}y}$ has a finite limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$. This limit must be zero in order for $F$ to be integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you, why didn't I see that, it was right before me. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it :)