# How do we prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2} + 7}$ converges?

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, improper-integrals

Tell if the following improper integral converges or not.
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2+7}\ \text{d}x$$

I know that a necessary but not sufficient condition is that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = 0$. Here this holds, so the integral might converge.

Now, I thought of the comparison:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2+7}\ \text{d}x < \int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2}\ \text{d}x$$

Since the second integral diverges, and the first one is $<$, it converges.

Is this method valid?

Comment: No. To prove convergence this way you need to find a larger integral that _converges_, Hinr: why/where does the second integral diverge? Can you fix that?

Comment: @EthanBolker Can I say that $$\dfrac{1}{x^2+7} < \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$$ and then conclude? The integral of $\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$ is the arctangent so it's convergent

Comment: Yes, your solution is the simplest. I suggest you [edit it as an answer to your own question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you!!

Comment: Incidentally, it is *not* a necessary condition for convergence of an improper integral that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$, in general.  (Though it is necessary for a nonnegative and decreasing function $f$.)

Comment: Indeed, [look](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370317).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh, I did not know. On my notes it was underlined as necessary... Thank you for having specified when it really is. Also, say I have $$\int_1^{+\infty} \dfrac{e^x}{(x+4)^2}\ \text{d}x$$

In this case, does noticing that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ straightly tell me that the integral diverges instead?

Comment: Yes, it's true that if $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, then $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges.  And also, if $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = L \ne 0$, then $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$ diverges.  It's when $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist that it's still possible for $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$ to converge.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I'm confused: when as $x\to +\infty$, $f(x) \to \infty$, the integral converges or diverges?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant diverges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your efforts, I would recommend you to split the integral into two parts as follows:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2} + 7} & = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2} + 7} + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2} + 7}
\end{align*}

The first part is integrable because its argument is a continuous function on the compact interval $[0,1]$, hence uniformly continuous and integrable. The second part is also integrable. That is because we can apply the monotonicity of the integral to conclude that:
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2} + 7} < \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{2}} = -\frac{1}{x}\bigg\rvert_{1}^{\infty} = 1 < + \infty
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In a simpler way, we can say

$$\dfrac{1}{x^2+7} < \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$$

Thence

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2+7} \text{d}x < \int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}\ \text{d}x$$

The second integral gives the arctangent function which evaluates to $\pi/2$. Hence

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2+7} \text{d}x < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Whence it converges.

To prove that the integral of $\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$ converges indeed, see @Atila Correia's answer!

Comment: Your last sentence is kind but inappropriate. You already proved "that the integral of $\frac1{x^2+1}$ converges indeed"!

Answer (score 1):

For $a>0$ we have  $$\int\limits_0^\infty {1\over x^2+a^2}\,dx=
{1\over a}\arctan\left ({x\over a}\right )\bigg\rvert_{0}^{\infty}={\pi\over 2a}$$
In OP case we have $a=\sqrt{7}.$