# uniformly continuous and $\int_0^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ exists $\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0 $

Tags: improper-integrals, uniform-continuity

I appreciate your help with this one.
Let $f \colon[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be uniformly continuous
and let the integral $\int_0^\infty f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ exist and be final.

I need to show that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = 0. $$

Thank you very much.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/f-uniformly-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-converges-imply-lim-x/92108).

Comment: @DavidMitra thank you very much! and im sorry for the duplicate.