# An exercise on $L^1$ function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose $f \in L^1 \cap C^1(\mathbf R)$, and assume $f'(x)$ goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$. What is the best way to prove that $f(x)$ also goes to $0$ as $x$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: contradiction: $f(x)=3$ , $f(x)'=0$

Comment: I forgot to mention that the domain is the real line.

Comment: Function defined by $f(x)=3$ is not in $L^1$ space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $f^\prime\in C^1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f^\prime(x)=0$, then $f^\prime$ is bounded in $[0,\infty]$. Say $|f^\prime(x)|\le M$ for $x\ge 0$. Now, it follows that $f$ is uniformly continuous in $[0,\infty)$

Now, a classic result implies that $\lim_{x\to\infty}|f(x)|=0$ (for example [$f$ uniformly continuous and $\int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx$ converges imply $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/f-uniformly-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-converges-imply-lim-x) )