# Nonnegative function with finite integral and Lipschitz implies bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lipschitz-functions

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is nonnegative, Lipschitz and has finite integral $\int f \, dx <\infty$. Is $f$ necessarily bounded?

I think it must be: if not, we can find a sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) > n$. And then integrating on $[x_n -1/2, x_n+1/2]$ we see that the integral is at least on the order of $n$, so by taking $n$ large, we get a contradiction.

Is this reasoning accurate, and can we give an explicit bound on $f$ in terms of the Lipschitz constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you mean globally Lipschitz, suppose with constant $L$.

Suppose $f(x) > 0$ then
$\int f \ge {1 \over L} f(x)^2$.

Hence $\sup f \le \sqrt{L \int f}$.

**Addendum**:

Since $f$ is Lipschitz, we have
$f(y)-f(x) \ge -L|x-y|$, or
$f(y) \ge f(x) -L|x-y|$.

Now note that $\int_{x-{f(x) \over L}}^{x+{ f(x) \over L}} (f(x) -L|x-y|) dy\ge {1 \over 2} 2 {f(x) \over L} f(x)$.

Comment: Can you explain the first inequality: $\int f \geq  f(x)^2/L$?

Comment: @DrewBrady: I added an elaboration. It might help to draw a little picture to see the triangle involved.

Comment: @cooper.hat Do you know if this bound is attained?

Comment: Take $f(x)=\max(0,1-|x|)$, Then $\int f = 1$, $L=1$, $\sup f = 1$.

Comment: Right -- what is the correct modification for $\sqrt{L\int f}$, though? If one tries $f(x) = (1 - L|x|)_+$, we obtain $L$ Lipschitz, but bounded by 1. The bound predicts $\sqrt{L}$. If one tries $f(x) = L(1 - |x|)_+$, again we have $L$ Lipschitz, but bounded by $L$; the bound predicts $L^{3/2}$, however.

Comment: Huh? $\sqrt{ 1 \cdot 1} = 1$. I don't follow what you are saying.

Comment: @cooper.hat Yes, I agree that your bound is optimal for $L = 1$. I am asking if your bound is tight in a stronger sense: let $L > 0$. Does there exist $f = f_L$ such that $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz and $\sup f = \sqrt{L \int f}$?

Answer (score 3):

So $f$ is uniformly continuous and integrable. It suffices to prove that $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$, for then $f$ must be bounded, but the answer has been given in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92105/f-uniformly-continuous-and-int-a-infty-fx-dx-converges-imply-lim-x).

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct. But there cannot be a bound depending only on the Lipschitz constant $C$. For any $M>0$ consider the function $f(x)=(M-|x|)^{+}$. This is Lipschitz with $C=1$ and it is integrable. But $f(0)=M$.